# Is it possible to give only view permission for Jenkins monitoring-plugin?

Tags: jenkins-plugins

We have the monitoring-plugin installed in our Jenkins: https://github.com/jenkinsci/monitoring-plugin

is there a way to give only view permissions once it is installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official answer from the developer is not at the moment:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14750